Does the local density approximation exchange functional obey the spin-scaling relation?
In density functional theory, the exchange energy functional has an analytic form under the local density approximation (LDA):
$$ E^\text{LDA}_\text{X}[\rho] = C_\text{X} \int \mathrm{d}^3r\, \rho^{4/3}(\mathbf{r}), $$
where $C_\text{X} = -\frac{3}{4}\left(\frac{3}{\pi}\right)^{1/3}$ is a constant. Also, it is derived in G. L. Oliver and J. P. Perdew, Spin-density gradient expansion for the kinetic energy (https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.20.397), that the exact exchange functional $E_\text{X}[\rho]$ satisfies the spin-scaling relation
$$ E_\text{X}[\rho_{\alpha}, \rho_{\beta}] = \frac{1}{2}\left( E_\text{X}[2\rho_{\alpha}] + E_\text{X}[2\rho_{\beta}] \right). $$
My question is: does the LDA exchange functional also satisfy the spin-scaling relation? I.e. does the following equation hold exactly?
$$ E^\text{LDA}_\text{X}[\rho_{\alpha}, \rho_{\beta}] = \frac{1}{2}\left( E^\text{LDA}_\text{X}[2\rho_{\alpha}] + E^\text{LDA}_\text{X}[2\rho_{\beta}] \right). $$
